# GA data is not being displayed in Google Ads report

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads-api

My question is related to the connection of google analytics data with google ads data.
I have auto-tagging enabled in GA and Google Ads. And I have "Allow manual utm_parameters overwrite auto-tagging parameters in GA".
In the link I have manually specified the utm parameters that are different to google/cpc and when clicking on the ad gclid is appended.
But I can't see any sessions assigned to any campaign in the report.

Do someone have any ideas why could it happen?
My utm_parameters for source / medium are different from google / cpc.  Could it be the reason?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have `gclid` and if you have `source / medium` other than `google / cpc`, Google will not be able to recognize that those sessions are from Google Ads, you will probably find them in the `(Other)` channel in Google Analytics.

Comment: Thanks Michele for the quick answer :) but in case we have gclid, but have source/medium other than google/cpc can't it recognize the google ads data?

Comment: If you have enable "Allow manual utm_parameters overwrite auto-tagging parameters in GA", il gclid is overeritten.

Comment: aah, ok, so we can't than map gclid from google ads with gclid from ga as it's being overwritten?